# Ant Build not giving the exact class files

Tags: java, ant, build

i created an ant build for my project.
I saw some different class names when extracted the jar file like myfile.class(r).
 and the size of this class file is not same as that of the compiled class files.
Why is this happening.
When i run the jar i got Exception that can not find the method.
But the jar i exported form eclipse working prfectly.

here is my build.xml file

```
<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

</path>

<manifestclasspath property="lib.list" jarfile=".">
        <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
</manifestclasspath>

<target name="clean" description="Clean output directories">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>


<target name="build" description="Compile source tree java files">
        <echo>copy src files</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${copy.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${copy.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                    <exclude name="**/*.class"/>
                    <include name="**/*.java"/>
                    <include name="**/*.properties"/>
                    <include name="**/*.MIB"/>
                    <include name="**/*.java.bak"/>

                </fileset>        
        </copy>


    <echo>Compiling the source code</echo>
    <echo>Apache Ant java version is ${ant.java.version}</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${copy.dir}" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="on">

        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}/src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.class"/>
            <include name="**/*.properties"/>
            <include name="**/*.MIB"/>
        </fileset>        
    </copy>  
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="build">



    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <echo>building jar!</echo>


    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" >



        <fileset dir="${build.dir}" >
                <include name="**/*.class" />
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
                <include name="**/*.MIB" />
                <include name="**/*.java.bak"/>
                <include name="**/*.png"/>
                <include name="**/*.jpg"/>
        </fileset>


        <zipfileset includes="**/**.**" src="${lib.dir}/junit.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/*.*" src="${lib.dir}/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/*.*" src="${lib.dir}/NicManager.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/**.**" src="${lib.dir}/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/*.*" src="${lib.dir}/snmp4j-1.11.3.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/*.*" src="${lib.dir}/snmp4j-agent-1.4.3.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/*.*" src="${lib.dir}/NMSLookAndFeel.jar"/>
        <zipfileset includes="**/*.*" src="${lib.dir}/rt.jar"/>   
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.ushustech.nmsazzist.NMSAzzistApp" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.list}"/>
        </manifest>

    </jar>
</target>
<target name="main" depends="clean,jar"/>
```

Comment: do you create your jar using Eclipse Export or Ant script?

Comment: i created it using Ant script.

Comment: Could you post the <javac> and <jar> part of your ant script?

Comment: Are you setting your Manifest correctly?

Comment: so why not you just Export it? When you Export you can save Ant script. Then you can compare with yours own.

Comment: [Video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGf8iiNBUjY) You need to select `Package required libraries` and `Save as ANT script`. Then you can compare

Comment: what this .class(r) indicates. Anybody knows that?

Comment: I assume "rt.jar" refers to the Java Runtime library - you should never embed this library into a JAR file you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem after some days. it's because of a duplicate jar file which also contains the classes that are in my project. those classes were look like myfile.class(r).